# Spring: Choose bean by default

Tags: java, spring

Project `Base`:

```
@Service
public class BeanDefault implements BeanBase {

}

public class App {
    @Autowired
    private BeanBase beanBase;
}
```

Project `MyDerived`(`Base` is the parent of `MyDerived` in maven and there are many other derived projects):

```
@Service
public class MyBean implements BeanBase {

}
```

And I want to class `App` use `MyBean` without disturbing other projects(They still Use `BeanDefault`).

I can modify the code in both project `Base` and `MyDerived`(couldn't modify the code of other derived projects), so how to do that:

- App use `BeanDefault` when it is the only qualifying bean for `BeanBase`
- App use `MyBean` in my Project

---

I find that works:

```
@Service
@Primary
public class MyBean implements BeanBase {

}
```

But I wonder,is it a good practice?

Comment: Your approach of using `@Primary` is good, however you will see that now you always get an instance of `MyBean`. To selectively get another instance you can give the bean a name and use `@Qualifier` annotation as described here - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Comment: @BijuKunjummen "you will see that now you always get an instance of MyBean" -- I think that only happens in my derived project... The other derived projects still use `BeanDefault`...

Comment: Ah, I see, yes you are right, your current approach will work for you.

Comment: It is right practice. Use it, no doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@Primary` is fine as long as more than one bean is annotated with `@Primary`. You can also use `@Qualifier`.

```
@Service("mySpecialBean")
public class MyBean implements BeanBase {

}

public class App {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mySpecialBean")
    private BeanBase beanBase;
}
```